# How to handle non configured variables in Sass

Tags: css, sass

In the following Sass file i'm creating a simple css structure where I can set up all the fonts in the first rows.

```
$global-font-family:          'Open Sans', sans-serif;

/*h1*/
$h1-font-family:               inherit;
$h1-font-size:                 4em;
$h1-letter-spacing:            inherit;
$h1-line-height:               inherit;
$h1-text-transform:            inherit;

/*h2*/
$h2-font-family:               inherit;
$h2-font-size:                 3em;
$h2-letter-spacing:            inherit;
$h2-line-height:               inherit;
$h2-text-transform:            inherit;

h3,h4,h5,ecc.


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  font-family: $global-font-family;
}

h1 {
  font-family: $h1-font-family;
  font-size: $h1-font-size;
  letter-spacing: $h1-letter-spacing;
  line-height: $h1-line-height;
  text-transform: $h1-text-transform;
}

h2 {
  font-family: $h2-font-family;
  font-size: $h2-font-size;
  letter-spacing: $h2-letter-spacing;
  line-height: $h2-line-height;
  text-transform: $h2-text-transform;
}

h3,h4,h5 ecc.
```

Firstly a font-family is applied to h1,h2,h3,p. Then, you can change every single tag, but is not necessary. For example, if you set a global font-family Open Sans to all, and h1 has to be Open Sans, you leave h1 blank.

But... how I leave h1 to Open Sans without removing this 
`h1 { font-family: $h1-font-family }`

is "inherit" the correct way? What would be the cleanest solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you are creating a template, I think it would be better to write just the global rules and let the users customize whatever they need in whichever model they prefer to do it. What I mean to say is that you should leave out all the `h1`, `h2` specific rules and let them write the selectors if they need. They can always override your CSS by appending custom rules.

But if you want to follow your model of *defining* the variable names that they should be using, setting the properties only if the expected variable is defined by the user then the [`@if`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_9) directive or the [`if()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method) function along with [`variable-exists`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#variable_exists-instance_method), [`global-variable-exists`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#global_variable_exists-instance_method) could be useful for you like in below snippet (its a reduced sample). I think this makes it ***really complex*** but its your choice.

```css
$global-font-family:          'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$global-font-size:            3em;

/*h1*/
$h1-font-family:               'Roboto Sans', sans-serif;

/*h2*/
$h2-font-size:                 1em;

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  font-family: $global-font-family;
}

h1 {
  @if (global-variable-exists(h1-font-family) or variable-exists(h1-font-family)){
    font-family: $h1-font-family;
  }
  font-size: if((global-variable-exists(h1-font-size) or variable-exists(h1-font-size)), 
                $h1-font-size, 
                $global-font-size);
}

h2 {
  @if (global-variable-exists(h2-font-family) or variable-exists(h2-font-family)){
    font-family: $h2-font-family;
  }
  font-size: if((global-variable-exists(h2-font-size) or variable-exists(h2-font-size)), 
                $h2-font-size, 
                $global-font-size);
}
```

`variable-exists` function checks if the variable is defined in the local scope whereas the `global-variable-exists` checks if it is defined in global scope. If it is defined then we use the value provided by the user. If else we do nothing or use the global font settings.

In the snippet, I've also demonstrated both the `@if` directive and the `if` function. They have subtle differences. The `@if` directive prints the property (`font-family` here) only if the variable exists while in the case of `if` function, as you can see, the property is printed irrespective of whether the variable exists or not. If the variable is present, it uses th user defined value else it uses the global setting. The choice on which one to use is upto you.

Below is the **compiled CSS:**

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Here since the `$h2-font-family` is not defined separately, it doesn't print the `font-family` here and so the global one defined in `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p` would get used.

---

**Note:** `inherit` doesn't mean inherit the value from the previous matching selector. It means inherit the value *from the parent*. So, for example if you need `body` to have `Arial` font, global setting is for `h1, h2, h3` to have `Verdana` then if you set `$h1-font-family` to `inherit`, it would apply `Arial` font to `h2` instead of applying `Verdana` (if user didn't define anything). This might not be what you're after.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h2 {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Some Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Some Heading 3</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you make variables in the first place is to make changes quicker and be able to be consistent. If you want to apply your h1 font to all headings or to primary headings name the variable after that. Or simply inherit. ex:

```
$font-heading-primary: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$font-heading-secondary: 'Halfway Sans', sans-serif;
$font-family-paragraph: 'Closed Sans', sans-serif;

$font-size-lg: 3rem;
$font-size-md: 2rem;
$font-size-sm: 1rem;

h1 {
    font-family: $font-heading-primary;
    font-size: $font-size-lg;
}
h2 {
    font-family: $font-heading-primary;
    font-size: $font-size-md;
}
h3 {
    font-family: $font-heading-secondary;
    font-size: $font-size-sm;
}
p {
    font-family: $font-paragraph;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, where is the $global-font-family? :)

Comment: Why would you globalize font-family to immediately override? The better approach is to just declare for what is necessary.

Comment: I would like to create a template with Sass and I don't know if users will use the global font or customize every tag...

Comment: I understand that, but from a designers point of view that restriction is not that bad. If the person knows what he is doing with design he knows how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of ways to about architecting your SCSS, but it's easy to get in a situation of overkill like your example. I would try to harness the power of the cascade if I were you; set the font family on the `body` or a base set of elements so you're not redeclaring it hundreds of times.

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea,
address,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
   font-family: $global-font-family;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I already did it
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p ecc {
  font-family: $global-font-family;
}

But if then I need to customize, for example, the h1?